# a very simple question about Control Input in SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation, ekf

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I recently began to learn SLAM. I read about the materials written by Hough Durrant Whyte, in which it states that the Control Input U is assumed already known. I wonder where the Control Input U come from.
The Complete statement is as following:

## The definition of SLAM problem

## No information about m is provided

## The initial location x0 is assumed known (the origin)

## **The sequence of control actions Uk is given**

## Build the Map m

## At the same time inferences about the locations of the vehicle Xk

## Recognise that the two inference problems are coupled.

Isn't the Control Input U is one output of the Kalman filter? If not, where does it come from?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/67162/a-very-simple--question-about-control-input-in-slam/) by [jizhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3558/jizhe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2013-07-11

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [l4ncelot](https://answers.ros.org/users/23971/l4ncelot/) on 2017-11-01**:
This is not ROS question. You should ask in other forums about questions not related to ROS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there, the control input U is the action that you input to the system. If you have a linearized equation of your system then the state space representation of it would be something like:

[image: image description]

In that case, *u(t)* is the input to your system. So if you have a car, it'll be the motor's speed.
You can read more about state space here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State-space_representation

---

Originally posted by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) with karma: 700 on 2017-10-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jizhe](https://answers.ros.org/users/3558/jizhe/) on 2017-11-02**:
I posted this question many years ago, and today I got the reply. Although I've known the answer, I still want to say: thanks very much!

**Comment by [bpinaya](https://answers.ros.org/users/28465/bpinaya/) on 2017-11-03**:
didn't notice that, glad I could be of help! And upvote would help ;)

**Comment by [Mark Rose](https://answers.ros.org/users/27558/mark-rose/) on 2018-06-28**:
As well as accepting the answer, if you liked it.